# Using Facebook Login unity PC Standalone Build

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have decided to go with PC standalone build becauce I had no luck with WebGL and facebook, because my build in WebGL is getting too big for a web game.

However when I push my "Login with Facebook" button, nothing happens on the PC standalone build. How can I use the Facebook SDK with Unity's PC standalone build?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure Facebook does not support PC builds. Simply looking at the source code of the SDK is enough to see that they simply have no implemented handlers for PC:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
ComponentFactory.GetComponent<EditorFacebookLoader>();
#elif UNITY_WEBPLAYER || UNITY_WEBGL
ComponentFactory.GetComponent<CanvasFacebookLoader>();
#elif UNITY_IOS
ComponentFactory.GetComponent<IOSFacebookLoader>();
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
ComponentFactory.GetComponent<AndroidFacebookLoader>();
#else
throw new NotImplementedException("Facebook API does not yet support this platform");
#endif
```

This is why "Login with Facebook" button does nothing in your build.

You could try implementing everything manually. You can work with Facebook using graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5

So you can use Unity WWW class to access various graph API nodes.

However you still an access token to use it, so you have to login somehow, and you have to pass through Facebook login dialog, which you don't have for your platform. So the best bet would embed browser in your game (there are some plugins that can do it), and do all the client side login flow via javascript https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web or manual login flow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

The same problem will occur if you are planning to use some standard dialogs, such as share or invite.

And last, your Facebook must be approved by Facebook review team before going public. I am seriously don't know how you are going to get this approval, since you are using an unsupported platform.

So this is what you will have to do to achieve what you want. Hope it helps.

Comment: Good point there... I should try to work this out with my web gl build...
Either way thanks for the info

Comment: @xjimdim on WebGL... check out the resources on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/canvas they may be useful. Also I recommend posting any issues you have with WebGL here for discussion (https://www.facebook.com/groups/491736600899443/)